# Matlab - inplace operation on anonymous array

Tags: matlab, expression

I'm new to Matlab and struggling with understanding the concept of array notation (coming from a Perl background).

Let's assume we have two random vectors (`X`,`Y`) which are coordinates in 2D (range `-r` ... `r`) and we want to find out which points (x, y) lie within a circle with radius `r`. This would be our setup:

```
 n = 100000000;              % point number
 r = 1;                      % circle size
 X = (rand(1,n) .* 2*r) - r; % generate coordinates (-r .. r)
 Y = (rand(1,n) .* 2*r) - r;
```

As I understood, Matlab is able to do almost anything fully vectorized on the way to classify the coordinates (in `C`):

```
 C =  -                          ... % negate sign, 1: within, 0,-1: outside
      sign(                      ... % -1: within, 0,1: outside
            (X.^2 + Y.^2) - r^2  ... % calculate distance
          );
```

Now I would like to retain only the values for points within the circle and therefore drop all `-1` (former >=0 values) values from `C`, which could be done by:

```
 C(C < 0) = 0;
```

I found no obvious way **to include the latter expression with the former** into a single expression, because I did not find out how the temporary array which is about to be created and modified by the distance-, sign-, and negation operators can be "addressed" to do another "step" with `C(C < 0) = 0`. Would this be possible at all?

**Edit**:

According to Dan's comment below, I could simplify the whole expression to:

```
 C = ( (X.^2 + Y.^2) - r^2 ) < 0;
```

which is exactly what I had looked for. Thank you very much! I didn't think *this* is possible in Matlab ...

Comment: I think you want `> 0` there as you're setting elements to `1` now, not to `0` as before

Comment: @Dan I tried to get 1-s as result to have the possibility of doing a `sum()` later. The `-`/`sign()`sequence was just a try to get there (I didn't know better)

Comment: Ah I didn't see you'd changed it. Much better that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific case I think you could just equate it to 1:

```
C =  -sign((X.^2 + Y.^2) - r^2) == 1;
```

or

```
C =  -sign((X.^2 + Y.^2) - r^2) > 0;
```

because what your output is in the end is just a matrix of `1`s and `0`s so you might as well take advantage of Matlab's logical datatype

But addressing the temporary matrix is not really the way to do things in Matlab. Normally you would just leave it as two lines of code. But if you really really want to, I think you can use the [`subsref`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsref.html) function to do it.